# Sending dynamic custom headers in swagger UI try outs

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using swagger in java.

I am reading a header called callerId through requestAttributes in the code. I am not using the header through the annotation @HeaderParam.

because of this reason, the header section is not showing up in the swagger UI for try outs.

How can I make this header show up in the try out form.

Is there any way I can achieve this without hard coding the header value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add parameters to an operation using @ApiImplicitParams and @ApiImplicitParam.

The following wiki documentation should provide you with an explanation on how to use these annotations - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations#apiimplicitparam-apiimplicitparams

Keep in mind I assume here that this is not a security header but actually part of the API (at least based on the description you gave). If you're looking for a security header, there's an alternative method. Please leave a comment and I'll edit this response.

Comment: Yes I am looking for an api header not a security header. I put the annotation but I am still not able to see this in the swagger UI or its being passed in the call. I am using jersey. @ApiImplicitParam(name = "name", value = "example", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"). Please advice.

Comment: You need to use `@ApiImplicitParam` as a value to `@ApiImplicitParams` (notice the singular and plural forms). Also, make sure the paramType is "header" otherwise you're adding a query parameter.

Comment: It worked. Thanks!.   
@ApiImplicitParams({@ApiImplicitParam(name = "callerId", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header")})

Comment: @Ron could you please mention the steps to add security header ?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the wiki first, and if that doesn't help, you can use our google group to ask the question.