# Using an API Key & Secret for Swagger Security Scheme

Tags: swagger

Swagger supports security of [api key](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#securitySchemeObject), but that seems to be limited to a single parameter.

Is there a way to define a set of parameters (key and secret) that are expected as parameters in a request?

Or is the only way just to skip the security scheme, and just add those parameters to every request?

Comment: Did you try this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742521/sending-dynamic-custom-headers-in-swagger-ui-try-outs

Comment: @suresh2 That would work, but was looking for an answer on if it's possible to do it as the security scheme. As far as I know, that would just be a required param. Which may work, just want to use the security scheme if possible.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, OpenAPI (Swagger) 2.0 and 3.0 let you define multiple security definitions and mark an operation as requiring multiple securities, such as a pair of API keys.

In the following example, I'm defining two API keys, `Key` and `SecretKey`, both of which should be present in the headers of each request in order to get authenticated.

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 0.0.0
  title: Simple API
securityDefinitions:
  key:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: Key
  secret_key:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: SecretKey

# Or if you use OpenAPI 3.0:
# components:
#   securitySchemes:
#     key:
#       type: apiKey
#       in: header
#       name: Key
#     secret_key:
#       type: apiKey
#       in: header
#       name: SecretKey

paths:
  /:
    get:
      # Both 'Key' and 'SecretKey' must be used together
      security:
        - key: []
          secret_key: []
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
```

Note that this is different from

```yaml
      security:
        - key: []
        - secret_key: []  # <-- Note the leading dash here
```

which means the endpoint expects either `Key` or `SecretKey`, but not both.

Comment: Thanks! Completely missed the `can have multiple security schemes` and what that practically meant in the spec.

Comment: btw, Swagger Editor now supports multiple securities. The issue is resolved.

Comment: So where do you set the secret API key?

Comment: @ChrisRich In the `swagger-ui.html` file, a button appears in the header bar next to your API URL with the name "Authorize". Click on that button to log in with your API key and send the requests from now on with that secret key.

Comment: Problem solved, [github issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/318) is closed;) Seems like we can use several keys

Comment: thanks but i am using 3.0 version , could not able to get the apiKey on index.html file.....can you please help me... i did below thing  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050969/setting-swagger-apikey-in-version-2-0

Comment: @Mohsen i am not geting apiKey @ url  in index.html , what should i do, please help me.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050969/setting-swagger-apikey-in-version-2-0

Comment: Why key is empty here , where are you supplying key here ? security:
        - key: []

Comment: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/api-keys/ describes the solution perfectly

Comment: @ssc-hrep3, Maybe this silly question but in the backend where we need to keep the API key in the swagger file?  is there a way we can pass this key on from the node environment?

Comment: @AshishYadav You would provide the actual API key by the front-end, you should not provide any key to swagger by the back-end side.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 for the response,  the thing was missing in the above example how we can call the node middleware handler which I found in some other example

Comment: I was trying to keep both api_key and main_auth. I was expecting AND instead of or between authentication. Your answer solved my problem. Thank you so much.