# Swagger - Adding multiple security parameters to the same schema definition

Tags: swagger

***Aim***

To include multiple security headers to every request made within the API

***Problem***

I am trying to add multiple headers to my Swagger YAML security definitions.
I have trawled though the API but not have alot of luck
But am finding that when making the 'Try-This-Operation' I am required to select one. Rather than able to use both. Is this correct or am I doing something incorrectly?

***Snippet***

```
securityDefinitions:
  userEmail:
    type: apiKey
    name: User Email
    in: header
  clientId:
    type: apiKey
    name: Client Id
    in: header

security: [ { userEmail: [], clientId: []  } ]
```

***Alternative?***

If I am trying to do this impossible ... 
Is it possible to specify these parameters as default for all the rest paths within the swagger document?

I am new to Swagger this week any have found everything else without problem ... but I cannot find any good example of this.

If any guidance could be given that would be incredibly helpful 
Many thanks

Comment: Side note: I chatted to developers on the Swagger IRC, and they believed this format is correct. They suggested it may not be the syntax but the Swagger editor that was incorrect. I will try this and post my findings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an API Key & Secret for Swagger Security Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817270/using-an-api-key-secret-for-swagger-security-scheme)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OAS 3: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/

> #### Using Multiple Authentication Types
>
> Some REST APIs support several authentication types. The `security` section lets you combine the security requirements using logical OR and AND to achieve the desired result. `security` uses the following logic:
>
> ```
> security:    # A OR B
>  - A: []
>  - B: []
>
> security:    # A AND B
>  - A: []
>    B: []
>
> security:    # (A AND B) OR (C AND D)
>  - A: []
>    B: []
>  - C: []
>    D: []
> ```

Comment: @Jon Whitefield pick this answer please, it's accurate and answers the question.

Comment: Answer accepted, my issue is long gone but reading though my question and a brief scan of the doc's suggest this would have fixed my problem ( untested though ). Many thank!

Comment: Hi @JBaczuk, the 2nd sample you provided above, is returning `security: [ { userEmail: [] }, { clientId: []  } ]` when exported as JSON via swagger editor, which, as per my understanding, is representing "A or B" instead of "A and B". Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Did you do `A: [] and B: []`? I have updated the answer to include the array (empty just for the example) that should contain scopes for clarity.

Answer (score 11):

Your `SecurityDefintions` object looks ok. Beware that

```
security: [ { userEmail: [], clientId: []  } ]
```

means the API client MUST use `userEmail` authentication AND `clientId` authentication at once! You probably meant:

```
security: [ { userEmail: [] }, { clientId: []  } ]
```

which means the API client MUST use either `userEmail` authentication OR `clientId` authentication.

To avoid repeating this definition over and over again you can use the global `security` property that applies to all paths without their own `security` object:

```yaml
security: [ { userEmail: [] }, { clientId: []  } ]
paths:
  "/foo":
    get:
    post:
```

or make use of a reference for explicitness or for multiple common values:

```yaml
paths:
  "/foo":
    get:
      security:
        "$ref": "#/definitions/lowSecurity"
    post:
      security:
        "$ref": "#/definitions/highSecurity"
definitions:
  lowSecurity:  [ { foo: [] }, { bar: []  } ]
  highSecurity: [ { foo: [] } ]
```

### Reference

The Swagger2 specification states under [Operation Object](http://swagger.io/specification/#operationObject):

> `security`:
>   [[Security Requirement Object](http://swagger.io/specification/#securityRequirementObject)]
>
> A declaration of which security schemes are applied for this operation. The list of values describes alternative security schemes that can be used (that is, there is a logical OR between the security requirements). This definition overrides any declared top-level security. To remove a top-level security declaration, an empty array can be used.

The [Security Requirement Object](http://swagger.io/specification/#securityRequirementObject) is described like this:

> Lists the required security schemes to execute this operation. The object can have multiple security schemes declared in it which are all required (that is, there is a logical AND between the schemes).
>
> The name used for each property MUST correspond to a security scheme declared in the Security Definitions.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was unable to find any official documentation about this. Would you be able to point to your information source, please?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I know it wasn't easy to understand that because of the implicit AND-/OR-logic and OpenAPI's different naming of OAuth2 entities. For official documentation see [Security Definitions Objects](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-definitions-object) and [Security Requirement Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-requirement-object)