# Swagger Codegen not generating API Key example in it's documentation

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am new to using Swagger Codegen so I assume I am doing something completely wrong. I have a remote swagger.json that I am using to generate a java client. Everything works and looks good but the example usages in the readme are not referencing any API key.

I don't have access to the remote API that I am using just trying to create a nice Java SDK for interfacing with it.

This is what I am using to generate the code.

```
java -jar C:/Development/codegen/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate 
  -a "client_id:XXXXXXXXXX,client_secret:YYYYYYYYYYYYY" 
  -i https://BLAH/swagger/v1/swagger.json -l java 
  -o C:/Development/workspace/JavaClient 
  -c C:/Development/workspace/JavaClient/java-genconfig.json
```

Then the example that get's generated in the read me looks something like this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BusinessGroupApi apiInstance = new BusinessGroupApi();
    Integer businessGroupId = 56; // Integer | The ID of the business group to fetch.
    String apiVersion = "1.0"; // String | The requested API version
    try {
        BusinessGroup result = apiInstance.getBusinessGroupAsync(businessGroupId, apiVersion);
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        System.err.println("Exception when calling BusinessGroupApi#getBusinessGroupAsync");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Side Note**
When I try running the example, I get an error saying

```
Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:443
```

Is there some setting that I need to set so it looks for the service at a remote location instead of locally?

**EDIT**

I realized that I needed to modify their swagger as they might not have everything fleshed out.

Swagger Codegen Version = 2.4.5

swagger.json (Excluded the paths and definitions) I also downloaded thiers locally and added some more info to make it generate more info. I added host, basePath, schemes, consumes, produces, security and securityDefinitions.

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "title": "removed"
  },
  "host": "apitest.removed.com",
  "basePath": "/removed/api",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "security": [
    {
      "clientId": []
    },
    {
      "clientSecret": []
    }
  ],
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "clientId": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "in": "header",
      "name": "client_id"
    },
    "clientSecret": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "in": "header",
      "name": "client_secret"
    }
  }
}
```

This actually updated the readme to look how I would expect it to look

```
    ApiClient defaultClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();

    // Configure API key authorization: client_id
    ApiKeyAuth client_id = (ApiKeyAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("client_id");
    client_id.setApiKey("YOUR API KEY");
    // Uncomment the following line to set a prefix for the API key, e.g. "Token" (defaults to null)
    //client_id.setApiKeyPrefix("Token");

    // Configure API key authorization: client_secret
    ApiKeyAuth client_secret = (ApiKeyAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("client_secret");
    client_secret.setApiKey("YOUR API KEY");
    // Uncomment the following line to set a prefix for the API key, e.g. "Token" (defaults to null)
    //client_secret.setApiKeyPrefix("Token");

    BusinessGroupApi apiInstance = new BusinessGroupApi();
    Integer businessGroupId = 56; // Integer | The ID of the business group to fetch.
    String apiVersion = "1.0"; // String | The requested API version
    try {
        BusinessGroup result = apiInstance.getBusinessGroupAsync(businessGroupId, apiVersion);
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        System.err.println("Exception when calling BusinessGroupApi#getBusinessGroupAsync");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Yet when I plug in my client_id and client_secret and try to run it I get a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at removed.Tester.main(Tester.java:18). I think I might have the security definitions not set up correctly.

It's not OAuth but they require a client_id and client_secret to be passed in the header parameters.

**EDIT 2**

```
Exception when calling BusinessGroupApi#getBusinessGroupAsync
package.client.ApiException: 
    at package.client.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:927)
    at package.client.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:843)
    at package.client.api.BusinessGroupApi.getBusinessGroupAsyncWithHttpInfo(BusinessGroupApi.java:148)
    at package.client.api.BusinessGroupApi.getBusinessGroupAsync(BusinessGroupApi.java:133)
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:30)
```

Line 30 -> BusinessGroup result = apiInstance.getBusinessGroupAsync(businessGroupId, apiVersion);

**EDIT 3**

I enabled debugging with

```
defaultClient.setDebugging(true);
```

It looks like it's working but for some reason doesn't like my client_id and client_secret despite them both being the ones I used in postman.

```
--> GET <removed>/api/api/businessGroups/56?api-version=1.0 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
client_secret: <removed>
client_id: <removed>
User-Agent: Swagger-Codegen/1.0-SNAPSHOT/java
--> END GET
<-- HTTP/1.1 403  (393ms)
Content-Length: 80
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 10 Jun 2019 20:05:07 GMT
QL-LB-Appliance: <removed>
QL-LB-Pool: <removed>
QL-LB-Server: <removed>
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: <removed>
OkHttp-Received-Millis: <removed>

{ "error": "invalid_client", "description": "wrong client_id or client_secret" }
<-- END HTTP (80-byte body)
Exception when calling BusinessGroupApi#getBusinessGroupAsync
<removed>.client.ApiException: 
    at <removed>.client.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:927)
    at <removed>.client.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:843)
    at <removed>.client.api.BusinessGroupApi.getBusinessGroupAsyncWithHttpInfo(BusinessGroupApi.java:148)
    at <removed>.client.api.BusinessGroupApi.getBusinessGroupAsync(BusinessGroupApi.java:133)
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:32)
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `https://BLAH/swagger/v1/swagger.json` (or a real link) and also the contents of `java-genconfig.json`? Which version of Swagger Codegen do you use?

Comment: Thanks, I just added a bunch more information with an EDIT. Not sure where I am messing things up as I am trying to bandaid the source swagger to achieve what I am aiming for.

Comment: What is on line 18 in `Tester.java`? Your swagger.json looks correct, except if you need both `client_id` and `client_secret` headers included at the same time, the `security` should look like this: `"security": [ { "clientId": [], "clientSecret": []  } ]` ([see this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34295389/113116) for an explanation).

Comment: I just made the suggested change in the swagger with security. Currently rebuilding a new version of swagger-codegen and will report back to see if this issue is still occurring. I will let you know where it hangs up on the tester too..

Comment: Added the new error and line location after a rebuild. Going to try with a newer version here in a sec

Comment: @Helen got a little further. Seems to be working just not accepting my client_id and secret.

Comment: Ah finally figured it out. Enabled debugging would have been a help from the start. Just need to clean up a few path and make sure I have the correct keys for the environment. I am currently cleaning it up now and will report back with the final answer. Thanks a ton @helen